# How to exchange deprecated getExtraInformation() in context of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am upgrading older Spring 2.5 code to Spring 3.0 (as a first step). During this I found the following problem:

> The method getExtraInformation() from the type AuthenticationException is deprecated

The point is that this happens in a subclass of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`:

```
@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse res, final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException
 {
  req.setAttribute("exception", authException);
  super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(req, res, authException);
  if (authException instanceof CredentialsExpiredException)
   {
    final User user = ((UserDetailsImpl)authException.getExtraInformation()).getUser();
    if (user.getCredentials().getUserCannotChange())
     {
      throw authException;
     }
    req.setAttribute("user", user);
    req.setAttribute("msg", this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.credentialsExpiredPleaseChange"));
   }
 }
```

Until now I found no way to get the User in another way. So my question is how to get the user when it is no longer transported via the exceptions extra information?

The point is that the User is required here, because a decision has to be made if the exception is only rethrown or if a message should be presented to the user.

Btw. I have found no code that creates a `CredentialsExpiredException` with `ExtraInformation`, so I assume this will be done by the Spring/Spring Security Framework?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to step back and do this "extra information" check when Spring Security checks if there is `CredentialsExpiredException`. Assuming you are using the default settings , the `CredentialsExpiredException` is checked in the `postAuthenticationChecks` `UserDetailsChecker` in `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. The default implementation is `DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks` which you can override it with yours :

```
public class MyPostAuthenticationChecks extends DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks {

      public void check(UserDetails user) {
            UserDetailsImpl userImpl = (UserDetailsImpl)user;
            if (user.getCredentials().getUserCannotChange()){
                throw new CredentialsExpiredException("Some customized error message blalblbal");
            }else{
                super.check(user);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: For Spring Security 3.0 I could only find `org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker`, but not `DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks` is it from a later Version or ist it in another package?

Comment: I can see that it is added in 3.1.0.M2 (this commit : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/091a6d26f19ee3a58d5ceb836835702b68fc479b#diff-621d7cfc8e5aa292a49efbbdcb0bbbc9)